# Откуда InetAddress.getByName(ip).getCanonicalHostName() берет имя хоста?

Tags: java, linux, сеть, ip-address

Написал простую программу, куда вводишь ip, а она должна выдавать хост.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Index {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите интерисующий ip:");
    String ip = in.nextLine();

    InetAddress addr = null;
    try {
        addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(addr.getCanonicalHostName());
}
}
```

Если я ввожу ip сервера на котором запускаю эту программу то получаю имя хоста. Если пытаюсь узнать хост другого сервера в этой же сети то получаю просто ip.

---

Поэтому вопроса 2:

- Откуда .getCanonicalHostName() узнает имя хоста.
- Где нужно прописать имя хоста на linux-сервере, чтобы код отработал как надо, возможно нужно указать где-то на DNS сервере?
  (В каких местах вообще это возможно сделать?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За преобразование ip в имена отвечают PTR записи в DNS. Все такие записи объявляются в "обратных зонах", являющиеся субдоменами домена in-addr.arpa. Если ip адреса внутренние, вам надо самому поднять "обратную зону" у себя в DNS. например для подсети 192.168.0.0/24 зона должна называться `0.168.192.in-addr.arpa`. Если адреса реальные, то обратные зоны, доступные в интернете, могут поднимать владельцы минимум подсетей класса C (256 ip-адресов).

Записи PTR в DNS выглядят как ip перевернутые задом на перед:

```
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   IN  SOA ns.sample.com. dns-admin.sample.com. ( 
                           1999040701 ;Serial number 
                           10800 ;Refresh 
                           3600 ;Retry 
                           604800 ;Expire 
                           86400)    

0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN   NS       ns.sample.com.

1.0.168.192              IN   PTR      hostname.sample.com.
```

Помимо этого можете попробовать прописать обычные "прямые" записи в /etc/hosts

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Еще одно замечание по вопросу. Есть 2 машины. Севрер и прокси. ip прокси прописан в dns, следовательно я могу его спокойно пинговать с сервера, как через ip, так и через имя хоста, НО! метод .getCanonicalHostName() почему-то не может вернуть имя хоста если я запускаю это приложение на сервере.

Comment: @АртемМежеловский ip прокси прописан в DNS в каком виде ? Если только в виде прямой записи `A`, то по ней может произойти только определения IP по имени хоста, но не наоборот. Если имя определяется, возможно оно определяется по файлу hosts на самой машине. А на сервере видимо в hosts нет записи и единственный путь, это поднять обратную зону и запись PTR в ней. И если правильные записи в DNS есть, то машина получающая адреса разумеется должна пользоваться именно тем DNS сервером

Comment: @ mike указны и A запись и PTR запись, но все равно getCanonicalHostName() не хочет выдвавть имя хоста

Comment: @АртемМежеловский На той машине где это не работает, попробуйте `dig PTR 2.64.0.10.in-addr.arpa` (ip только нужный кажите), если dig нет, то можно запустить nslookup, в нем дать команду `set q=PTR` и вбить этот же in-addr адрес. они должны вернуть определенное по DNS имя.

Comment: Разобрался.В чем была проблема:
1. Не было  PTR записи.
2. Нужно было почистить кэш на внутреннем dns сервере